# Coldfusion Builder 3 Console Issue

Tags: macos, coldfusion-11, coldfusionbuilder

I have CF Builder 3 installed.  I have CF 11 Developer (Tomcat and Apache) on the same machine (Mac running Yosemite).  I can use RDS to connect to the datasources, I can use RDS to connect to the file structure, and I can use the debug perspective to do breakpoints, etc.

However, I can not get anything to show up in the console when I do 

or 
writeDump(now(), "console").

Anyone ever see this?